# How to reimplement the map method in ruby using recursion?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm a ruby newbie, learning to code. I wanted to understand how some of the methods available from the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html) module work. So I'm reimplementing them. One challenge was to implement them using recursion. However, I'm running into a problem when trying to implement the [Enumerable#Map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method using recursion.

This is my code:

```
class Array
  def mymap_recursive(&block)
    copy_of_array = dup
    new_array = []
    return new_array if copy_of_array.empty?
    value = copy_of_array.shift
    new_array << yield(value)
    copy_of_array.mymap_recursive(&block)
  end
end
```

I tried to figure out why it wasn't working so I put

```
puts "#{new_array}"
```

at the end of the method. Then in Sublime Text, I did

```
arr = [2,2,5,5,10]
arr.mymap_recursive {|n| n * n}
```

After pressing cmd+b, the output I got was:

```
[100]
[25]
[25]
[4]
[4]
```

I cannot figure out why its not returning one array with all the values.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: in line 3 you return new_array (which is []) if copy-of-array is empty.
Where do you return it with something else in it?

Comment: To me line 3 represents the base case where the recursion should break if the condition is true. I thought it would just return a new_array with all the values in it.

Comment: Yes, that is the base case... and it will only ever return new_array with nothing in it.. because that's what it has in it after you assign [] to it... ;)
you also have to have a case where you return new_array with *something* in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening in your code is every time you call `mymap_recursive(&block)` the `new_array` is being lost. To solve this you must have a way to maintain the new array that is being built recursively. A simple change to your code is including `new_array = []` in your method definition, then passing new array each time. Here would be the code with my changes in place:

```
class Array
  def mymap_recursive(new_array = [], &block)
    copy_of_array = self.dup
    return new_array if copy_of_array.empty?
    value = copy_of_array.shift
    new_array << yield(value)
    copy_of_array.mymap_recursive(new_array, &block)
  end
end
```

Then when you call

```
arr = [2,2,5,5,10]
p arr.mymap_recursive {|n| n * n}
#returns
#[4, 4, 25, 25, 100]
```

If you have any questions over this syntax or anything let me know and I will try my best to explain it!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which doesn't change the method signature and doesn't mutate any data:

```
class Array
  def mymap_recursive(&block)
    if empty?
      []
    else
      [block.call(first)] + drop(1).mymap_recursive(&block)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping! I have a question about this method though: isn't line 6 dropping an element from the original array that the mymap method is being called on?

Comment: Yes. But it also processes the dropped element, too, before the plus sign.

Line 6 performs two tasks, separated by the plus sign. Before the plus sign it takes the "first" element of the array and calls the block (in your example "n * n") on it. After the plus sign it drops the first element (the one that's already been squared), and applies this method to all the remaining elements. Then, the + operator joins both sides.